# Bash script execute shell command with Bash variable as argument

Tags: bash, variables, command

I have one loop that creates a group of variables like DISK1, DISK2... where the number at the end of the variable name gets created by the loop and then loaded with a path to a device name. Now I want to use those variables in another loop to execute a shell command, but the variable doesn't give its contents to the shell command.

```
for (( counter=1 ; counter<=devcount ; counter++))
do
    TEMP="\$DISK$counter"

# $TEMP should hold the variable name of the disk, which holds the device name
# TEMP was only for testing, but still has same problem as $DISK$counter

    eval echo $TEMP  #This echos correctly

    STATD$counter=$(eval "smartctl -H -l error \$DISK$counter" | grep -v "5.41" | grep -v "Joe")
    eval echo \$STATD$counter

done
```

Comment: Expected output? Actual output?

Comment: output was irrelevant as this question was about functionality

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `eval` ever, except maybe if there is no other way AND you really know what you are doing.

The `STATD$counter=$(...)` should give an error.  That's not a valid assignment because the string "`STATD$counter`" is not a valid variable name.  What will happen is (using a concrete example, if counter happened to be 3 and your pipeline in the `$( )` output "output", bash will only expand that line as far as "`STATD3=output`" so it will try to find a command named "`STATD3=output`" and run it.  Odds are this is not what you intended.

It sounds like everything you want to do can be accomplished with arrays instead.  If you are not familiar with bash arrays take a look at [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), in particular [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) or the bash man page to find out how to use them.

For example, in the loop you didn't post in your question: make `disk` (not `DISK`: [don't use all upper case variable names](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet?highlight=%28uppercase%29#Parameters)) an array like so

```
disk+=( "new value" )
```

or even

```
disk[counter]="new value"
```

Then in the loop in your question, you can make `statd` an array as well and assign it with values from disk by

```
statd[counter]="... ${disk[counter]} ..."
```

It's worth saying again: avoid using `eval`.

Comment: evals are great if you wanna basterdize things like make a 2 dimensional array ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just converted it all to arrays and that solved the whole problem. As for the STATD$counter, that didn't even matter because it was failing to evaluate the $DISK$counter (spit out the contents) when it tried to execute the shell command, so it never got as far as trying to assign anything to the 'basterdized' STATD$counter variable. :-) So even though you didn't quite answer why $DISK$counter wouldn't expand, you bumped me in the direction I should have started in. Thanks!

Comment: @sdproto: Are you sure it is the `\$DISK$counter` portion that is failing?  That part should expand correctly and your comments / test echo before that seem to confirm that.